# Fallo en adapter de App para hacer preguntas test

Tags: android, android-studio, arrayadapter

Estoy haciendo una App de preguntas test y a la hora de hacer el adapter debo de tener algún error porque al ejecutar la App ésta se cierra automáticamente. La actividad principal es la siguiente:

```
public class ActivityTest extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button back;
    private Test test;
    private ListView listViewTest;
    private TextView textViewQuestion;
    private ArrayAdapter<Question> adapter;
    private RadioButton[] radioButtonsAnswers;
    private int contOK;
    private boolean[] Verify;
    private String correctAnswer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
        test = GeneradorTest.generarTest();
        listViewTest = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewtest);
        adapter = new TestAdapter(this,R.id.activity_pregunta,R.id.textViewQuestion,R.id.imageViewQuestion,R.id.radiogroup_answers,R.id.check,test.getQuestions());
        listViewTest.setAdapter(adapter);
        back = (Button)findViewById(R.id.back);
        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Con esto la pregunta se generaba bien y mostraba la pregunta y las posibles respuestas.

Al poner el siguiente adapter es cuando da error y la App se cierra:

```
public class TestAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Question> {
    private int buttonGroup;
    private int imageViewQuestion;
    private int imageViewVerify;
    private int[] radioButtons;

    public TestAdapter(Context context, int layout, int textViewQuestion,  int imageViewQuestion, int buttonGroup, int imageViewVerify, List<Question> objects) {
        super(context, layout, textViewQuestion, objects);
        this.buttonGroup = buttonGroup;
        this.imageViewQuestion =imageViewQuestion;
        this.imageViewVerify = imageViewVerify;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View result = convertView;
        RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) convertView.findViewById(buttonGroup);
        ImageView imviewQuestion = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(imageViewQuestion);
        ImageView imviewVerify = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(imageViewVerify);

        Question q = this.getItem(position);

        imviewQuestion.setImageBitmap(q.getImage());
        if(q.getResposta()==-1 || !q.isCorrect()) {
            imviewVerify.setImageBitmap(null); //imatge a mostrar
        }
        else{
            imviewVerify.setImageBitmap(null); //imatge correcte
        }
        rg.check(q.getResposta());
        for(int i=0; i<q.getRespostes().length; i++) {
            ((RadioButton)rg.getChildAt(i)).setText(q.getRespostes()[i]);
        }
       // rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener();//quan canvi el seleccionat, modifica resposta
        return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    }
}
```

El error que me da es el siguiente:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
```

Agradecería si alguien pudiera saber donde puede estar el error.

Otra cosa que me gustaría saber es como implementar el setOnCheckedChangeListener()  para poder cambiar la respuesta seleccionada.

Gracias.

Comment: pon el error que te da el android studio que siempre ayuda

Comment: Gracias ya lo he editado

Answer (score 2):

El error indica :

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null
>   object reference

Lo que quiere decir que tratas de llamar el método `findViewById(int)` en una vista con valor null, el error se produce al tratar de obtener una referencia de un elemento en una vista pero esta vista, `convertView` tiene un valor null :

```
RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) convertView.findViewById(buttonGroup);
ImageView imviewQuestion = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(imageViewQuestion);
ImageView imviewVerify = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(imageViewVerify);
```

Lo que se realiza generalmente dentro del método [getView()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView(int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup)), es revisar si el contenedor `convertView` contiene valor, si no es así tienes que inflar la vista que contiene los elementos que buscaras dentro de la misma:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


   if( convertView == null ){
    //Creamos la vista:
       convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_list_item, parent, false);
    }

      //  View result = convertView;
        RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) convertView.findViewById(buttonGroup);
        ImageView imviewQuestion = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(imageViewQuestion);
        ImageView imviewVerify = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(imageViewVerify);
```

Puedes ver unos ejemplo de Adapter y revisar lo que se realiza dentro de [getView()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView(int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup)) :

[ListView y Adapter personalizado.](http://www.proyectosimio.com/es/programacion-android-listview-adapter-personalizado-i/)

[Adapter personalizado en Android.](https://elbauldelprogramador.com/adapter-personalizado-en-android/)

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas inflar tu vista antes de poder acceder a ella, fíjate en este ejemplo:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   // Get the data item for this position
   User user = getItem(position);    
   // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
   if (convertView == null) {
      convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_user, parent, false);
   }
   // Lookup view for data population
   TextView tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
   TextView tvHome = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvHome);
   // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
   tvName.setText(user.name);
   tvHome.setText(user.hometown);
   // Return the completed view to render on screen
   return convertView;
}
```